# How to delete QLabel and QwtSlider in a std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qwt

I have a `std::vector` filled up with `QLabel` and `QwtSlider` pointers and I would like to delete the pointers but not the vector.

Here my code:

```
QLabel *sliderSimuVarLabel;
std::vector<QLabel*>    labelsSimuVarList;
std::vector<QwtSlider*> slidersSimuVarList;

int num = 3;
for (int i=0; i<numSimuVars; ++i){

   sliderSimuVarLabel = new QLabel("Hello", Widg);  
   sliderSimuVarLabel->setFont(panelFont2);

   labelsSimuVarList.push_back(new QLabelWidg));                                      
   labelsSimuVarList[i]->setFont(panelFont2);

   slidersSimuVarList.push_back(new QwtSlider(Qt::Horizontal,Widg));

   layoutSimuPanel->addWidget(sliderSimuVarLabel,i+7,0);
   layoutSimuPanel->addWidget(slidersSimuVarList[i],i+7,1,1,5);
   layoutSimuPanel->addWidget(labelsSimuVarList[i], i+7, 7);
}
```

I don’t know with which method delete the pointers: `clear()`? `deleteLater()`? others?

Comment: Follow the discussion here : http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/43978/

Comment: I usually set the parent and let Qt handle the deletion. Although this may be a problem if the parent object stays around longer than you want the children.

Comment: Yes @drescherjm, this is the case. I would like that the parent stays longer than the children. Should I create a child QWidget of the parent? If yes, how delete the child QWidget later?

Comment: In that case you should be able to do what @vahancho said in his answer.

Comment: I applied the @vahnancho solution and worked! thank you to all!

Answer (score -6, accepted):

To remove objects (pointers) from your vector and delete them you can:

```
// Remove elements from the back
while (!labelsSimuVarList.empty()) {
    delete labelsSimuVarList.back();
    labelsSimuVarList.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: Does it have the same meaning of `QVector::clear()` ?

Comment: @Tay2510 Clearing vector will free pointers, and not objects. If you want to clear content of Qt container use `qDeleteAll`

Comment: `qDeleteAll` takes a pair of iterators and is not tied to Qt containers at all.

Comment: -1 for terrible manual memory management. Smart pointers please.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::unique_ptr`. In this case you do not have to do anything to clear up the objects afterwards, and it's safe in the case of things like exception or early return. Do not ever `delete` anything yourself, as it is terribly unsafe to do so. I believe that Qt also provides some smart pointers of its own, and Boost also provides `shared_ptr` and others for you to use.

Comment: -1 because it's awfully vague and vaguely incorrect. To use `std::unique_ptr` or the equivalent `QScopedPointer` in a container requires C++11 and a container that supports move semantics, since the smart pointers are not assignable nor copyable. With C++11, you don't even need to use a `std::unique_ptr`. You can simply emplace the non-copyable `QObject` instances in a `std::list`. The only non-C++11 solution is to use `std::shared_ptr` or `QSharedPointer`, with all the memory locking overhead it entails (it's not really shared except for short time when things are moved around).

Comment: The only "real" solution to this problem would be a modern reimplementation of `QPtrList` and `QPtrVector` from Qt 3, perhaps as a container adapter. I'm sure something like that must exist somewhere... ah yes, the [Boost pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) library.

Comment: @KubaOber, doh, what. I mean, what.

Comment: @KubaOber You're talking like it's hard to get your hands on a C++11 implementation these days.

Comment: @KubaOber, I mean: OH NOES IT REQUIRES C++11 A.K.A. THE THREE YEARS OLD (NOT TO MENTION CURRENT) STANDARD.

Comment: @KubaOber: It is the current Standard and `unique_ptr` is one of the earliest implemented features for all major compilers. Even Microsoft has supported it for years by this point. Also, quit crying about the locking overhead of `shared_ptr`, nobody's gonna care how fast the OP's code is when he throws an exception and leaks all his objects, and you don't even know he's in a hot path that will have any performance relevance anyway.

Comment: @KubaOber Oh no the performance of my UI-code-that-mostly-sits-idle will tank if I use shared_ptr. Modern implementations use atomics for maintaining the reference count so 'locking overhead' is non-existent anyway.

Comment: Again, you're vague since you can't just stuff `unique_ptr` into any container. It won't compile. It will compile if you use it with `std::vector` and `std::list`, but won't with, say, `QVector` or `QList`. That's because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable nor copy-constructible. I don't know if it works with `std::` containers due to their move semantics or due to specializations for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: There's a simple solution to woes related to Qt containers being terrible: don't use Qt containers.

Comment: @KubaOber Standard containers are move aware, that's why they allow non copyable types.

Comment: @KubaOber: It works with all C++11-compliant containers. Also, there's really no reason to use QVector or QList.

Comment: @DeadMG Except if you wish to interoperate with Qt, and then your code gets sprinkled with conversions all over the place. Never mind that the working set grows, as oft-running code is using two sets of containers. The boost-based solution isn't any good in this respect, I admit, and I presume that heap-use-wise the C++ and Qt containers are comparable.

Comment: In any case, I really don't see why bother with `std::unique_ptr` in C++11. If you have a `std::list`, you can simply emplace the instances, no need for explicit pointers at all. That's IMHO how it should be done in C++11.